# if $B$ is open then $x + B = \{x + y ~|~ y \in B\}$ is also open.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

> Let $B \subset \mathbb{R}$ be open. Then, $\forall~x \in \mathbb{R}$, prove that the set $x + B = \{x + y ~|~ y \in B\}$ is also open.

**Remark:** A set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is open $\iff \forall ~x \in A ~\exists~ \varepsilon > 0$ such that $(x - \varepsilon, x + \varepsilon) \subset A$.

**Attempt:**

Using the hypothesis that $B$ is open we have that $\forall~ y \in B~ \exists~ \varepsilon > 0$ such that $(y - \varepsilon, y + \varepsilon) \subset B$.

So,

$$ y \in  (y - \varepsilon, y + \varepsilon) \tag{1}$$

$$ y - \varepsilon < y < y + \varepsilon \tag{2} $$

$$ y + x - \varepsilon < y + x < y + x + \varepsilon \tag{3}$$

$$ y + x \in (y + x - \varepsilon, y + x + \varepsilon) \subset x + B \tag{4}$$

I'm not sure if $(4)$ implies $x + B$ is open.

Comment: It would be great to know what results are you allowed to use? Do you need to prove it directly by definition?

Comment: the map $f:y\mapsto x+y$ is an isometry, i.e. $d_{B}(p,q)=d_{f(B)}(f(p),f(q))$ for all $p,q\in B$. Here $d_B$ is interpreted to to be the metric on $B$. Isometries are homoemorphisms. Since homeomorphisms ae continuous, they send open sets to open sets.

Comment: @David yes, the proof must be elementary as this is from a first course in real analysis and nobody there has studied topology before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is neither correct nor wrong. After the word “So”, your proof consists simply of mathematical expressions without words connecting them, and so it is not a proof.

You want to prove that $x+B$ is open. An element of this set as a number of the form $x+y$, for some $y\in B$. Since $B$ is open, there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(y-\varepsilon,y+\varepsilon)\subset B$. But then $(x+y-\varepsilon,x+y+\varepsilon)\subset x+B$.

Comment: Yes, this is more of a proof sketch.. I understand I should formalize my argument better. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The map $f(y) = y-x$ is continuous and $x+B = f^{-1}(B)$. Since $B$ is open, so is $x+B$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

(1) For a fixed $x \in \Bbb R$ , $f_x: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ defined by, $f_x(y)=x+y$ is a homeomorphism.

(2) Restriction of a homeomorphism is again a homeomorphism.

(3) Homeomorphic image of an open set is again open.

Comment: Since this is a first course in Real Analysis and nobody in this class has studied Topology before, i don't think this argument would be accepted as a proof.. anyway a different perspective is appreciated.

Comment: @VictorS. I agree with you but when one works on more general objects such as a topological group, then my argument is the standard one!

Answer (score 1):

4 implies B is open but 3 doesn't imply 4.

Obviously $x + y - \epsilon < x+y + \epsilon$.  That's true for all $\epsilon$ no matter how big or how small.  But that doesn't mean $(x+y-\epsilon, x+y+\epsilon)\in x+ B$.

For example:  If $B=(0,1)$ and $x=5$ and $\epsilon=52$ and $y=13$ then we have $5+13-52 < 5+13 < 5+13+52$.  But that doesn't mean $(5+13-52, 5+13+52)\subset 5+(0,1)$

Now, you may argue that you never would have chosen that $y$ or that $\epsilon$ in the first place as $y\not \in B$ and $(y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon)\not \subset B$ in the first place.

And that's true but you must make your argument pertainent.

....

You need to proof that for every $x+y\in B$ there is an $\epsilon$ so that $(x+y-\epsilon,x+y-\epsilon) \in x+B$.

So:

For any $x+y \in x+B$ then $y \in B$.  (Actually you could be a little more careful with this: [For any $w \in x+B$ there is a $y\in B$ so that $w=x+y$; would be a better argument.  But this is good enough.])

And $B$ is open so there is an $\epsilon$ so that $(y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon)\subset B$.

Does that mean $(x+y-\epsilon, x+y+\epsilon)\subset B$?

Yes... but let prove that.

Let $w\in (x+y-\epsilon, x+y+\epsilon)$.  Then

$x+y-\epsilon < w < x+y +\epsilon$

$y-\epsilon < (w-x) < y-\epsilon$.

So $w-x \in (y-\epsilon, y+\epsilon)\subset B$.  So $w-x \in B$.

So $x+(w-x)=w \in B$.

So $(x+y-\epsilon,x+y+\epsilon) \subset x+B$.

So for any $x+y\in x+B$ there does exist an $\epsilon>0$ so that $(x+y-\epsilon,x+y-\epsilon)\subset x+B$ so $x + B$ is open.

=======

That was very picky and detailed.

It'd be acceptable to say:

The points of $x+B$ are precisely the points that are $x$ more than the points of $B$.  For any point $w$ of $x+B$ there is a point $y\in B$ where $w=x+y$ and as $B$ is open there is a interval of some radius $\epsilon$ around $y$ that is entirely in $B$.  So the set of $x$ plus the points of that interval will be an interval of radius $\epsilon$ around $x+y$ and consist entirely of points $x$ more than points of $B$. Which means that interval is entirely withing $x+B$.  So $B$ is open.

.....Hmm... I guess that *isn't* easy to read, write, or follow.... It was when I was composing it in my mind.

I guess my point is.  It's intuitive that $x+B$ is just a "shift" from $B$ so every thing said about $B$ and points of $B$ can be said about $x+B$ and points of $x+B$ by shifting.  That's not a proof, but it's  a guideline that proof would be everything said about $y\in B$ can be demonstrated to be identical to saying it about $x+y \in x+B$.

Comment: yes I thought the same thing, this is just a shift of the original set B and therefore it wouldn't change the fact that B is open, however that is exactly what has to be proved. thanks for the collaboration anyway.

Comment: Right but i)$x+B$ is "$B$ with a shift" means the $x+y\in B$ and $y\in B$ are in 1-1 corespondence ii) so for any *arbtrary* $x+y\in x+ B$ we determine a $y\in B$. iii) $B$ open means there is $\epsilon$ so every $w\in (y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon); w\in B$. ic) the "shift" means every $x+w\in(x+y-\epsilon,x+y+\epsilon); x+w\in x+B$. v) $x+y\in x+B$ was arbitrary (see i) and ii)). We have proven $x+B$ is open.  Ta-da!